# Finite subsets of countable and uncountable sets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

If I take all the subsets of exactly size $n$ (where $n$ is some fixed natural number) from the set of *natural* numbers, and put them into a set, then the result is a *countable* set (a set containing all subsets of size $n$).

If I do the same, but this time taking the subsets (of size $n$ - I'll call them $n$-subsets) from the reals, then the result is an uncountable set.

Can someone please explain to me why this is the case? And perhaps how to show it?
I guess it's because the natural numbers contain a countable number of $n$-subsets, and the reals contain an uncountable number of $n$-subsets. But I don't know how to formalize this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "the $n-$ subset of the reals" ?

Comment: I mean a subset with n elements... Sorry if I wasn't being clear enough

Comment: Do you mean taking $n$ reals to form a subset? If that is the case then it is countable, by definition. If instead you want to find the cardinality of the class of subsets with $n$ elements then it is a of course different.

Comment: I mean taking all the subsets of exactly n elements and putting them into a new set.
In the first case the subsets come from the natural numbers, in the second case they come from the reals

Comment: I don't mean a union, I mean a set containing all subsets of exactly size n.. sorry for being vague

Comment: I have edited my post to reflect this the best I can

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $n$ be only $1$. The set of all subsets of one element of the reals is already uncountable since it is equivalent to the set of reals.

So the harder question is why the set of $n$-touples of natural numbers is countable. It is easy! Take $n$ different prime numbers: $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ and observe that an $n$-tuple of naturals $\{n_1,n_2,...n_n\}$ uniquely determine one natural number

$$N_{n_1,n_2,...,n_n}=p_1^{n_1}\times p_2^{n_2}\times \cdots \times p_n^{n_n}.$$

This why you can construct only a subset of the naturals...

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. I guess I would just use induction to show this for any n, then?

Comment: Why? Is it not enough to say that if $n>1$ then there will be "more" objects? All the objects of one element form a set contained in the set containing longer sequences. (Better said: equivalent of a subset of ...) ??? But a little induction is always fun : ).

Comment: Of course, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

We can (injectively) map the set of $n$-subsets of a set $X$ into $X^n$, hence there at most as many $n$-sets as therre are $n$-tuples - and in case of infinite $X$ we have $|X|=|X^n|$. This shows that there are *at most* as many $n$-sets as elements if $X$ is infinite.

If $X=\mathbb N$, we can also injectively map $X$ to the set of $n$-subsets of $X$ by mapping $a\mapsto \{a,a+1,\ldots,a+n-1\}$. More generally, if $X$ is infinite, we can write it as disjoint union of countable subsets and repeat this construction piecewise. This shows that there are *at least* as many $n$-sets as elements if $X$ is infinite.

In summary, the cardinality of the set of $n$-subsets of $X$ is the same as the cardinality of $X$ (if $X$ is infinite).

Comment: Very good answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the set $A_i$ are such that $|A_i|=n$ and $$\mathbb R=\bigcup_{i\in\mathcal I}A_i$$
then the union is not countable since $\mathbb R$ is not countable.